# Migrating from MySQL to MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb

I am trying to migrate to MariaDB 10.5.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

**Problem:**
I am specifically, having trouble importing my mysqldbdummp.sql file into the new Mariadb.

**My Steps**
1.) First, I dumped all my dbs into a .sql file `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_dbs.sql`
2.) Then, I removed the mysql server from ubuntu `sudo apt purge mysql-server`
3.) From here, I installed mariadb:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
`sudo apt -y install software-properties-common`
`sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys 'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc'`
`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.5/ubuntu focal main'`
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client` # I foolishly answered "no", since it was telling me it was safe to do so...
4.) I tried import my dbdumpfile.sql   using `mysql -u root -p < all_dbs.sql` , but ran into this error `'ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`, so I used [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04) to solve that problem
5.) Which, of course, led to a new problem: `Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' #1902`, which I solved with `sed -i all_dbs.sql -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g'`
6.)And -now- when I run `mysql -u root -p < all_dbs.sql`, it outputs
`ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 87: Can't create table` mysql`.`db `(errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")`

Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `mysql` database and all its table insertions from your `all_dbs.sql` file. MariaDB-10.4+ doesn't maps its mysql table to MySQL-8.0 where you're importing from.

You'll need to look at `show create user {user}@{host}` and `show grants for {user}@{host}` to migrate system users.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up.. would you be able to provide some specific steps to achieve what you have said, much appracited